# Are there references about universal power series and this statement?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, power-series, uniform-convergence, analytic-functions

The notion of universal power series is linked with this statement :

> We can find a power series $\sum_{n\ge1} a_nx^n$ such that for all continuous function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=0$ there exists a strictly increasing sequence of integers $(n_k)_{k\ge 0}$ such that the sequence $S_{n_k}(x)=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{n_k}a_nx^n$ is uniformly convergent to $f$.

So if anyone has references to dig this notion or this statement it would be great to share ! Is it a useful result ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The singular of "series" is "series"; there is no such thing as a "serie".

Comment: Also, it's hard to understand what you mean by the question "why is it a powerful result?" Are you asking why the result is useful, or are you asking why such a "powerful result" is possible?

Comment: This can't quite be true as written--maybe there is supposed to also be an assumption that $f(0)=0$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Indeed my mistake !

Comment: @BenGrossmann It is more like why this result is useful.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ok so it is called "the universal power series of Sierpinski and Mazurkiewicz" !